# Show determinant of matrix formed by trace of basis of ring of integer is independent of the basis chosen

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $d \not \in \{0, \pm 1\}$ be a square free integer. Let $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in O_d$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of the ring $O_d$ of algebraic integers of $\mathbb{Q}_\sqrt{d}$. Consider the 2 by 2 matrix $M$ whose $(i,j)$-entry is given by Tr$(\omega_i \cdot \omega_j)$. Prove that the determinant det($M$) is independent of the choice of a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis {$\omega_1, \omega_2$}.

I have initially thought that the basis can only be {$1, \sqrt{d}$} for $d\in 2+4\mathbb{Z}$ or $3+4\mathbb{Z}$ and {$1, \frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$} for $d\in 1+4\mathbb{Z}$, but realised that the basis can be in the form of $a+b\sqrt{d}$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Upon doing some research, apparently a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis is also a power basis in the form of $\{1,d,\dots, d^{n-1}\}$, which doesn't look right as I am only taking two elements as basis. So i turned back to what I did at first, but brute force didn't get me the answer I want.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: The point is that any two bases are related as $\pmatrix{\omega_1'\\\omega_2'}
=A\pmatrix{\omega_1\\\omega_2}$ where $A$ is an integer matrix with determinant $\pm1$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Oh. is this referring to the one in binary quadratic form that any two similar forms can be obtained by multiplying to a matrix that has determinant $\pm 1$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown also in this case, how do I find Tr$(\omega_1, \omega_2)$ and Tr$(\omega_1', \omega_2')$? Or one in terms of the other?

Comment: Kenny, that's similar! You get the matrix with those traces as a product of two matrices. One with rows of conjugates of the elements of an integral basis, and the other factor as a transpose of that. Then you multiply by $A$ from one side, and by $A^T$ from the other - quite like when handling quadratic forms.

Comment: I think I am completely lost. Is there any document that I can refer to? Cannot find anything like this in the notes my professor gave.